# Correct identification of scientific journal?

Tags: journals, science

I'm new to academic writing. From what I read on other posts, would the "133" be the volume number? And the 46-54 be the page in the journal?

J Surg Res. 2006 Jun 1;133(1):46-54. Epub 2006 Apr 21.

From: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16631200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Journal of Surgical Research
Volume 133, Issue 1, June 2006, Pages 46–54

Answer (score 1):

You are right. 133 is the volume number and (1) is the issue number of the journal, while 46-54 indicates the page numbers. Since you are new to academic writing, a little bit of information on referencing and citation styles would probably help.

There are several style guides such as the APA, MLA, Harvard, and CMS style guides. Of these, students and researchers in the sciences and the social sciences generally follow the APA style guide. The APA style uses in-text citations as well as a separate reference list at the end. Typically, when referencing journal articles, the format used is as follows:

Author, A.A.. (Publication Year). Article title. Periodical Title, Volume(Issue), pp.-pp.